# how to pass expander header height from XAML to convertor

Tags: wpf, expander

I have two expanders in a StackPanel with a lot of content. Lets name them as A and B. When A is open and B is closed, I want A to obtain max_height = window_height - height_of_header_of_B. I want to do this using convertor.

My problem is that I am not being able to pass height of expander B's header to converter.

Comment: What method you have tried? sent header with ElementName binding ?

Comment: name property is not available with Expander.Header

Comment: thats not what i meant, how you tried to send the expander?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Grid x:Name="MyMainGrid"> 
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:MaxHeightConverter x:Key="MaxHeightConverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
        <Expander x:Name="E1"
                  Header="E1">
            <Expander.MaxHeight>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MaxHeightConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="E2" Path="ActualHeight" />
                    <Binding ElementName="MyMainGrid" Path="ActualHeight" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Expander.MaxHeight>
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <TextBlock>
                    This has long content
                    <LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak />
                    End
                </TextBlock>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Expander>
        <Expander x:Name="E2"
                  Header="E2">
            <Expander.MaxHeight>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MaxHeightConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="E1" Path="ActualHeight" />
                    <Binding ElementName="MyMainGrid" Path="ActualHeight" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Expander.MaxHeight>
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <TextBlock>
                    This has long content
                    <LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak />
                    End
                </TextBlock>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Expander>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Converter:

```
public class MaxHeightConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length != 2 || !(values[0] is double) || !(values[1] is double)) throw new ArgumentException("Incorrect parameters passed to MaxHeightConverter");
        return (double) values[1] - (double) values[0];
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```